# Immutable object pattern

Tags: thread-safety, semaphore, immutability

I keep hearing that using immutable data structures and immutable objects is a good pattern for thread safety and preventing race conditions without needing to use semaphores, but I still can't think of a way to use them. Even for the most simple scenarios. For example

```
int a = 0;
Semaphore s = new Semaphore();

void thread1() {
    s.wait();
    if (a == 2) {
        // do something
    }
    a = 1;
    s.signal();
}

void thread2() {
    s.wait();
    if (a == 1) {
        // do something
    }
    a = 2;
    s.signal();
}
```

How can I change this code to use an immutable object for `a`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does `a == 1` mean, and what does `a == 2` mean?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young nothing special. Just a simple example where a is being read and assigned to simultaneously.

Comment: Well, obviously, if you're assigning shared state, then it's not immutable. Programming in an immutable way requires you to not use mutable shared state (so all mutable state must be thread-local). So you'd have to restructure your program with that goal in mind, which brings me to the question, _why_ are you updating that variable? What is its purpose?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young That's actually my question. How can I restructure this code? If all states are thread local then how do threads communicate with each other? By the way the code I wrote isn't a real world example. It's just something I made up for the purpose of this question.

Comment: I would use a `BlockingQueue` that is shared between threads, to be used purely for message-passing. All state changes are done in response to messages from the queue.